# SharePoint Rest Api Filter not working and restrict to a site collection

Tags: 2013, rest

The rest query is as follows, I want to get most viewed pages. I have used `ViewsLifeTime` property. This query returns some pages (unwanted) which their `ViewsLifeTime` is null.

```
https://domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentTypeId:0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39*'&sortlist='ViewsLifeTime:descending'&filter=ViewsLifeTime gt '0'
```

I have tested with eq, ne as well.

The ViewsLifeTime of unwanted pages is like:

```
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
  <d:Key>ViewsLifeTime</d:Key>
  <d:Value m:null="true"/>
  <d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
```

But I want to have those pages is viewed (ViewsLifeTime is not null) like:

```
 <d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
   <d:Key>ViewsLifeTime</d:Key>
   <d:Value>14</d:Value>
   <d:ValueType>Edm.Int64</d:ValueType>
 </d:element>
```

The other problem with this query is it returns all pages within the farm. I want to get pages only from current Site collection.

How do I filter out those pages that have not been viewed (ViewsLifeTime is null) and restrict the result to current Site Collection?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the $filter parameter works on the search API.  You need to specify the filters in the querytext parameter.

```
querytext='ContentTypeId:0x010100C568*+AND+ViewsLifeTime>0'
```

As for the specific to site collection.  There is a WebID property for the querytext, not sure about Site Collection.

What I do is test my querytext in the standard SharePoint search box to get my query string value for my api calls!

Comment: Try level=sitecol for site collection only

Answer (score 0):

First enable *Search* and *Query* property for "**ViewsLifeTime**" managed property in search service and perform full crawl.

Use Search Query API for not returning the items for which "**ViewsLifeTime**" count is null

```
https://domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='NOT(viewslifetime:0)'
```

Reference Links :- 
[Filter for Empty Values in Search](https://www.itunity.com/article/filter-empty-values-search-693)